# Using jQuery to dynamically add tabindex on fields not marked as readonly

Tags: jquery, html

I have a large form with a number of dynamically generated textboxes.  I'm trying to set the tabindex automatically, but only for textboxes that don't have the readonly attribute set.  Cannibalizing several snippets here, but can't get it to work.

```
   $(function () {
        var tabindex = 1;
        $('input').each(function () {
            if (this.type != "hidden" && this.not('[readonly]')) ) {
                var $input = $(this);
                $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
                tabindex++;
            }
        });
    });
```

I know I'm messing up here:

```
&& this.not('[readonly]')
```

I'm sure this is simple, think I've been looking at it too long.

Comment: `this.not('[readonly]')` should be `$(this).not('[readonly]')`. Need to wrap your dom element into a jquery object. `this` refers to the element itself. you want `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector that only grabs the items you want, use the index passed to the `each` callback to set the tab index.

```
$(function () {
    let inputs = $('input:not([type=hidden]):not([readonly])')
    inputs.each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('tabindex', i+1)
    })
})
```

Comment: I like how simple this is, but for some reason it is only working on the readonly fields

Comment: Just tested here - seems to be working fine as far as how your question reads. Adds tabindex to all inputs that do not have readonly as an attribute and that are not of type hidden: https://codepen.io/mindfullsilence/pen/ajZLQP

Comment: It's weird, it works if I start at the second textbox (tabindex=1), but not on the very first one (tabindex=0).  If I go into the code and set the first textbox tabindex to 1, it works.

Comment: If you need the tabindexes to start at one, you can add 1 to i inside the callback. I've edited the code above to reflect this.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, thanks for following up

Answer (score 0):

```js
// like this
console.log( $('input').not('[readonly]').length );

// or this
console.log( $('input:not([readonly])').length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="text"/>
```